# xpath text() comparison

Tags: java, text, xpath

(new to web development)
Hi, can anyone explain me why this

```
Object x=getCurrentPage().getByXPath("//div[@class = 'notification']
                                       /text() =
                                      'Product saved successfully'").get(0);
```

returns a `Boolean false` object, but this

```
Object y = getCurrentPage().getByXPath("//div[@class='notification']
                                         /text()").get(0);
```

returns `DomText` object with data `Product saved successfully`?

why is the boolean `false`? it seems to me it should return `true`.

p.s. when i try the same query in XPathBrowser (FF plugin) it returns `boolean:true`

thanks a lot

Comment: Are you perchance doing this in HTMLUnit?

Comment: Suggest posting relevant bits of your sample input, **and** a little more code where you check and access the values of x and y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>Use:</del>

```
//div[@class='notification']/text()[ . = 'Product saved successfully']
```

Because the *collection* `//div[@class='notification']/text()` will never equal the *string* 'Product saved successfully'.

As Alejandro & LarsH pointed out (and they're both right), this answer was utterly wrong. The point is not that `//div[@class = 'notification']/text() = 'Product saved successfully'` doesn't work, it's just that the `.get(0)` doesn't make sense on the boolean the first option returns (it simply states `true`, as in 'that node exists')

Comment: that's what i was looking for. SO makes programming too easy

Comment: If you still need a boolean, surround with `count(...) > 0`

Comment: @Wrikken and @seminolas: In fact, comparison with node set are **existencial** comparison. So, you are asking if there is some text node child of some `div` with attribute `class` with `'notification'` string value, having `'Product saved successfully'` string value. This result in a true boolean value (because your second query). The problem might be in the DOM method used to query: it allows to return other than node set results? Besides that, @Wrikken expression will **select** the desired node.

Comment: @Wrikken, @seminolas, I believe this answer is wrong. As @Alejandro pointed out, `=` comparing a string with a nodeset (not a "collection", which is something else in XPath) is an existential comparison: "Is there any node in the nodeset whose string value  equals the given string?" And from the looks of things it should be true. As for why it returns false, we'd probably have to see the input document.

Comment: @Wrikken: ".get(0) doesn't make sense on the boolean it returns" - sure about that? getByXPath is supposed to return a **list** of values (http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getByXPath(java.lang.String)), and @seminolas **is** successfully retrieving a boolean object from it. If getByXPath were not returning a list, surely get(0) would throw an error?

Comment: Not very sure, I rarely dabble with Java, and I'm not capable of setting it up as a test right now. My normal XPath goto's don't care whether they return an boolean/integer/string/nodeset/element, that's up to the XPath expression itself. But be my guest, a simple testXML is easily made, and you're probably more versed in Java then I am. Returning a list seems silly for a boolean expression, but you've got a point that the documentation claims it should _always_ be a list..

Comment: @LarsH: +1 For finding the documentation (I couldn't!).

Answer (score 1):

Your first xpath is doing a boolean operation while the second is asking for text from the DOM.

EDIT: This is a response to the initial question (see revisions), not the question at present (which has changed).

Comment: He wasn't asking why the first XPath is returning a boolean, but why is it returning "false" instead of "true"?

Comment: Why don't you check the revisions before down voting someone? He added this: 'why is the boolean false? it seems to me it should return true.' in the last revision! If you look at the first revision my answer is correct.

Comment: OK, sorry about that. However it won't let me undo my downvote unless you edit your answer. If you do edit it, let me know (use @LarsH) and I'll un-downvote.

Comment: No worries, it wasn't fairly obvious (that the question changed) - I realized that after initially getting irritated :)